# fetch data from db and compare with user inputs

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

i am creating a code for email confirmation link. user inserted email id , n stores in db. Next time when user insert id into form, first of all it will check whether email id is already present in db or not. If y then said 'already exists' & if n then insert it into db. Initially i am inserting data into db. then i want to compare user input email is with db email id. so i dont know how i retrieve data on pg then compare it. here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email Id</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="mail" required  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $fname="'".trim(addslashes($_POST["fname"]))."'";
    $lname="'".trim(addslashes($_POST["lname"]))."'";
    $email="'".trim(addslashes($_POST["mail"]))."'";
    $key="'".MD5(microtime())."'"; 
    $to=$email;
    $subject="Confirm your email id";
    $message="Hello $fname
Click on below link to confirm your id.
www.vs.com/abcdefghojklmnopqrstuvwxyz.php?code=$key
";
    $header="From :sneha@valencynetworks.com";
    // echo $fname."<br />".$email."<br />".$to."<br />".$subject."<br />".$message."<br />".$header;   
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$header))
     {
        $sql="insert into confirm_emailid values($email,$fname,$lname,$key,'1')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
          die("Check your id for confirmation".mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }


/*$sql1=mysqli_query($con,"select * from random_key where eid=$email");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
 {
    echo $row['eid'];
 }*/ 
$result="SELECT count(eid) as number_of_occurences FROM confirm_emailid WHERE eid = $_POST['mail']";
if ($row['number_of_occurences'] == 0) {
  echo "this adresse isn't in the database, so add it !";
}
else {
  echo "already in the database :(";
}
mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Ajax for compare this email field with database emails.
Steps :

1. List item
2. On focusout from email field call ajax request
3. This ajax request fields contain user entered email
4. on php page its checks whether email exists o not if exists it gives false flag and if not it gives true flag.
   4.From this method you can check email without page loading.

Comment: i don't know ajax so not posible for me to do in ajax.

Comment: Its just simple.
Include jQuery and focuseout event of email field
$("#email").focuseout(function(){
AJAXCODE
});

Comment: Yes I know that you are newer that's why  I am suggesting you.
Please refer this link
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Try this in test file and implement this in project.

Answer (score 0):

When your form is submited, you have an array $_POST.
So, you just have to select from your database the sames values : exemple :

SELECT count(id) as number_of_occurences FROM member WHERE mail_adresse = $_POST['e-mail'] ;

You fetch the data like you did other times, and just compare $row['number_of_occurences'] to 0.

```
if ($row['number_of_occurences'] == 0) {
this adresse isn't in the database, so add it !
}
else {
 already in the database :(
}
```

Comment: ok but @Marveylabs can u tell me above ur code where i put it?? after completed mail fun & before closing mysqli_close fun  or in new php code

Comment: You have to send query to know if this mail exist, so before mysqli_close, and you need that the form is submited, so put my code where you receive your data.

Comment: I have updated php fun it gives me error. plz check it.

Comment: count(eid) : id or eid?
You have to test if your form was submited (if(isset($_POST)){  YOUR SCRIPT HERE; }

Comment: it's eid. i have already tested code it sends mail as well as insert value into db but it can't show when i used select query. display nothing . may be i was writing wrong query. so plz check whether i wrote r8 query or not in code

Comment: Send me the query too, and upvote and check my answer (in stackoverflow) if you understand

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="process.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email Id</td>
                <td><input type="email" name="mail" required  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>



</body>
```

process.php

```
  <?php


    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "yourpass";
    $database = "your database name";



   // Establish server connection and select database
    $dbh = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      die('Unable to connect to database ' . mysqli_connect_error());
   } else {

  // run query to fetch records
    // $result = mysqli_query($dbh, "SELECT  email_address FROM users ");
   /* fetch associative array */


  $email = $_POST['mail'];

  $query = "SELECT `eid` FROM `confirm_emailid` WHERE `eid` = '$email'";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbh, $query); //$link is the connection



  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


      die('email already exists');
  } else {

      $query = mysqli_query($dbh, "insert into users(email_address)   values('$email')");

     echo 'data inserted succesfully';
         }
       }
```

Comment: but @monir009 in my code how i retrieve db email field using select query because it can't run. i don't knw whr am going wrong.

Comment: what is your table and column  name exactly is?

Comment: table is confirm_emailid and col name is eid

Comment: then simply write "select eid from confirm_emailid" in the query field to retrieve email .

Comment: yes i used select query but no use, it cant show me result. using select query it gives result in array so i write mysqli_fetch_assos() bt no use..